# Umbraco - Reading the nodes

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a umbraco solution, which has a below piece of code in my view,

```
var home = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1);
var primaryNav = home.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("primaryNav").Where(n => n.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hideFromNavigation") == false);
```

From my Umbraco back office, can someone please tell me how can i find the nodes which satisfy the above piece of code.

I'm trying to a new node to the existing navigation bar, but it is not coming up. What could i be missing here?

Please let me know, i'm new to umbraco.

My Umbraco version is 7.2.1

Also, what could be the meaning of "primaryNav", here `home.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("primaryNav")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the root page of the website in the back office content tree. On that page there should be a content picker called something like "Primary Nav".

That should show up all of the selected items that should appear. It's also checking for a hide from navigation property, which you'd have to check individually on each of the selected nodes.

How are you trying to add the node to the menu? If it's via the picker, then it SHOULD work, unless the page has the hide from navigation checkbox checked. Also make sure you publish the root page once you've added the page to the picker rather than just saving.

The only other thing that might be causing it to not show up would be if the Partial that renders the navigation is being cached. Look in the view and see if it's using CachedPartial, and if so, that may be your culprit.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. There was a content picker in the root page after adding a new node there, it started coming up on the page